# C++ Anonymous function with return value

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu, return-value, anonymous-function

I have a simple requirement which involves passing function pointers to another function, and executing them there.
The function is given below.

```
void drawPolarCurves(Canvas &cnv, Point2 center, float (* fx)( float ), float (* fy)( float ));
```

I try to pass anonymous functions as parameter, as below.

```
void drawMyShape(Canvas &cnv, Point2 center, float width, float height)
{
    drawPolarCurves(cnv, center,
            [&width](float x)-> float { return x * width; },
            [&height](float x)-> float { return x * height; }
            );
}
```

This produces the following error:

Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
void drawPolarCurves(Canvas &, Point2, float (*)(float), float (*)(float))
'

I checked again and again and everything seems to be right, including the Eclipse compiler arguments on Ubuntu.

Thanks

Comment: Your calling code doesn't contain anonymous functions. It contains lambda expressions.

Comment: @Kerrek-SB: Thanks for point it out. I've never used the lambda expressions before...

Answer (score 3):

A lambda expression with a capture can not be implicitly converted to a function pointer, without a capture it could.

Ways to fix your problem:

- don't capture a value in your lambdas
- change the signature of `drawPolarCurves` to accept `std::function<float(float)>` or a template argument

Comment: I changed the function signature to this: void drawPolarCurves(Canvas &cnv, Point2 center, std::function<float(float)> fx, std::function<float(float)> fy)

Still errors: Symbol 'function' could not be resolved, Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: void drawPolarCurves(Canvas &, Point2, ?, ?)'

Comment: @inam101 Did you include the header `functional`?

Comment: yes, I have included it: #include <functional>. I think it might be confused with #include <iostream> for std...

Comment: @inam101 Does your compiler support `std::function`? I don't understand what you mean by confused with `iostream`. See this example http://ideone.com/k6TgEu